# Count items in List(Of structure) using predicate in .NET 2.0/VB.NET

Tags: .net, value-type, generic-list

I need to count the items that meet a criteria in a `List(Of Structure)` in .NET 2.0. For example:

```
Dim listcars as New List(Of car)

Structure car
   Dim Name as String
   Dim year as Integer
End structure
```

Now I need to count all cars with name Toyota, etc.. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `List.LongCount`.

```
Dim CarList As New List(Of Car)
Dim Model As String = "Toyota"
Dim ToyotaCount As Long = CarList.LongCount(Function(car) car.Name = Model)
```

Comment: Hello, i get this error `'LongCount' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of SubmitForce.mdlGeneral.Car)`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bit about .Net 2.0.  I think predicates are out of the question for what you want to do unless you write your own class inheriting `List`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim toyotas As Integer = carList.Count(Function(c) c.Name = "Toyota")
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but i get an error `Public ReadOnly Property Count() As Integer' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
 var count = carList.Count(x => x.Name == "Toyota");
```

Comment: you are using linq, but am using vb2005, can this be converted to a anonymous function

Comment: `dim count as integer = carList.Count(Function(x) x.Name = "Toyota")`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is blatantly wrong, but something like this:

```
Dim toyotas as Integer;
toyotas = 0;
foreach(car c in listcars){
    if(c.Name == "toyota")//make sure to do string comparison here.
        toyotas++;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not what am looking for/ i know how to use for each loop, but i said using predicate in my question