# not sure how to explain group and count list of items in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Let's say I have a DataGridView with the following data:

```
item1
item1
item2
item2
item2
item2
item3
```

What direction would I go to create a list like this from that data:

```
2 x item1
4 x item2
1 x item3
```

It's basically saying how many times a item has appeared in a list and displaying the number of times and the name of the item.

Read line 1, "item1" create counter, read each item in the list, when the strings match increment counter, go to the next item skip items already counted.

This is what I have so far, but it seems kinda overly complex. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

```
Dim counter = 0
    Dim listbox As New ListBox 'to store items already scanned
    listbox.Items.Clear() 'clear it on each new call
    listbox.Items.Add("Test") ' add a dummy value to start the loop
    For Each row In DataGridView1.Rows 'check each item in the datagridview

        Dim ItemName = row.Cells(1).Value 'declare the initial itemName
        Dim flag = True'set the continue bool to true
        For Each LoggedItem In listbox.Items 'check each item in the listbox to see if it has been check already 
            If LoggedItem = ItemName Then
                flag = False 'if the item has been checked set the continue bool flag to false to prevent it from adding and displaying the item again
            End If

        Next 'check next item in listbox 
        If flag Then

            counter = 0 'reset item counter
            For Each row2 In DataGridView1.Rows
                Dim ItemName2 = row2.Cells(1).Value
                If ItemName = ItemName2 Then
                    counter += 1 'checks each item in the datagridview again and counts how many matches it finds
                End If
            Next

            listbox.Items.Add(ItemName) 'add scanned item to the already checked list
            MsgBox(counter & " x " & ItemName) 'display item totals

        End If
        flag = True 'reset flag for next item
    Next  'continuum to next item
```

Comment: There's a nice answer with a lamba function here. One line of code: [Count items in List(Of structure) using predicate in .NET 2.0/VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823139/count-items-in-listof-structure-using-predicate-in-net-2-0-vb-net) Might need a list of distinct items first and use that to iterate the counts?

Comment: i will have to check it out if by you mean a list of distinct items as a pre defined list of items then i wont be able to generate that as the data in the list will change every time thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a little linq, you can get the bulk of that done in a single line. By using a linq grouped enumerable collection, you can get a distinct list of values along with their counts, and then output the results however you'd like. Here's a winforms example you can paste right into a new project to get you started:

> Code I used to set up the test:

```
'Create DataGridView and add it to the form
Dim dgv As New DataGridView With {
    .Location = New Point(50, 50),
    .Size = New Size(150, 300),
    .AllowUserToAddRows = False
}
dgv.Columns.Add("Column1", "Column 1")
Me.Controls.Add(dgv)

'Put some test data in it
Dim testValues As String() = {"item1", "item1", "item2", "item2", "item2", "item2", "item3"}
For Each testValue As String In testValues
    dgv.Rows.Add(New String() {testValue})
Next
```

> Getting the distinct values and their counts:

```
'Now to the question at hand...
Dim column1GroupedValues = dgv.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow).Select(Function(row) row.Cells(0).Value.ToString()).GroupBy(Function(x) x)
Dim outputString As New System.Text.StringBuilder
For Each grpVal In column1GroupedValues
    outputString.Append(String.Format("{0} x {1}" & vbCrLf, grpVal.Count.ToString, grpVal.Key))
Next
MsgBox(outputString.ToString)

'Outputs:
'2 x item1
'4 x item2
'1 x item3
```

The magic all happens where we create `column1GroupedValues`. We're telling linq to get the first cell's value in each row and then group them. Once you have that collection, you've got access to each entry's `Key` and `Count` properties, which you can display in whatever way you need to.